# How do I access form1 action and data with submit button of form2 in html

Tags: html, submit-button

I found xhtml that looks like this:

```
        <div class="mail_area">
        <div class="mail">
        <div class="mail_lef"></div>
        <div class="mail_cen">
        <form action="">
        <input type="text" value="Enter your E-mail for instant 
        access..." name="Enter your E-mail" class="txtinput"      onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue"/>
</form>
</div>
<div class="mail_rig"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="arrow_area">
<div class="left_arr"></div>
<div class="cen_but">
<span class="cen_text"><sup class="red">*</sup>We value your privacy and would never share your information.</span>
            <form action="">
                <input type="button" class="button" name="submit" align="middle"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="rig_arr"></div>
    </div>
```

In the first form I am going to add a method and an action.
It looks as though the second form was created this way so it could be lined up with other images.

So my question is, how can I setup the button in the second for to use the input information and get access to the action attribute of the first form?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just make this into one form? Because that's really what should be done (:

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to turn this into one form instead of two. Otherwise you would have to use javascript.

```
<form action="">
    <div class="mail_area">
        <div class="mail">
            <div class="mail_lef"></div>
            <div class="mail_cen">
                    <input type="text" value="Enter your E-mail for instant access..." name="Enter your E-mail" class="txtinput" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="mail_rig"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow_area">
        <div class="left_arr"></div>
        <div class="cen_but">
            <span class="cen_text"><sup class="red">*</sup>We value your privacy and would never share your information.</span><br>
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" align="middle"/>
        </div>
        <div class="rig_arr"></div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to override a `<form>` submitting data with the button you must:

A. Assign an id to the first form (in demo `#form1`)

B. Add the following attributes to the button:

1. Replace <del>`type="button"`</del> with `type="submit"`
2. Add `formmethod="post"` (or `get`)
3. Add `formaction="https://httpbin.org/post"` (The value is a live test server)
4. Add `form="form1"` (The value is the id of the targeted `<form>`)

### Demo

**This demo submits to a live test server, look for the form data in the JSON sent as the response to verify that it works**

```html
<div class="mail_area">
  <div class="mail">
    <div class="mail_lef"></div>
    <div class="mail_cen">

      <form id='form1' action="">
        <input type="text" value="Enter your E-mail for instant access..." name="Enter your E-mail" class="txtinput" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" />
      </form>

    </div>
    <div class="mail_rig"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="arrow_area">
  <div class="left_arr"></div>
  <div class="cen_but">
    <span class="cen_text"><sup class="red">*</sup>We value your privacy and would never share your information.</span>

    <form action="">
      <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="https://httpbin.org/post" form="form1">
    </form>

  </div>
  <div class="rig_arr"></div>
</div>
```